# Que signifie « autant que » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens

> Sans doute, on y reconnaît à juste titre des phénomènes de sociologie totale : autant que l'hérédité d'une population, une existence commune s'exprime dans ces chiffres.

Comment: dans la mesure où

Comment: ***Tout comme*** l'hérédité d'une population, une existence commune s'exprime dans ces chiffres. — ***De la même façon que*** l'hérédité d'une population, une existence commune s'exprime dans ces chiffres. — La phrase serait plus facile à lire sans l'effet de style de mettre le verbe à la fin : *Tout comme/De la même façon que* l'hérédité  d'une population s'exprime dans ces chiffres, une existence commune s'y exprime aussi.

Comment: @Lambie *Dans la mesure où* ne peut pas remplacer *autant que* dans cette phrase, si c'est ce que tu as voulu dire avec ton commentaire. Je suis très surpris par le +1.

Answer (score 3):

*Autant que* signifie ici *aussi bien que*, *de la même façon*.

> Dans ces chiffres, l'hérédité d'une population et une existence commune s'expriment [avec la même intensité]/[de la même façon]/[autant l'une que l'autre].

L'auteur aurait pu aussi écrire :

> Tant/aussi bien l'hérédité d'une population qu'une existence commune s'expriment dans ces chiffres.

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette phrase « autant que » sert à exprimer que la réalité d'une hérédité de la population et la réalité d'une existence commune sont reflétées par les chiffres avec une importance égale. On pourrait réécrire cette phrase comme suit sans changer le sens.

- dans ces chiffres s'exprime une existence commune  autant que l'hérédité d'une population

*ou*

- une existence commune  autant que l'hérédité d'une population s'exprime dans ces chiffres

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autant)) I.− Adv. de compar. exprimant en phrase compar., explicite ou implicite, l'égalité de deux procès, quant à leur intensité, leur quantité ou leur valeur.
> **A.** − Autant est suivi d'une prop. complétive, d'un terme de compar. introd. par le corrélatif que.
> **1.** [La compar. est explicite.]
> **a)** [La prop. princ. n'est pas attributive]
> − **[Avec ell. des termes autres que le suj.]**
> ♦ J'avais renoué connaissance avec le vieil ami de mon père, qui jadis prenait soin de mes intérêts : ce fut chez lui que je vis la jeune personne pour laquelle je ressentis un amour qui devait durer autant que ma vie. Balzac, Le Médecin de campagne,1833, p. 215.

*formulation sans l'ellipse*

- autant que **s'exprime** l'hérédité d'une population, une existence commune s'exprime dans ces chiffres (*Cette répétition est très lourde et ne sera jamais faite.*)
- dans ces chiffres **s'exprime** une existence commune  autant que s'exprime l'hérédité d'une population (*Dans le présent arrangement la répétition devient  acceptable.*)